# Issues using json.load

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print a list of commit messages from a git repo using python. The code I am using so far is:

```
import requests, json, pprint


password = "password"
user = "user"
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/MyProduct/ios-app/commits", auth=(user, password))
j = json.load(r.json())

jsonData = j["data"]
for item in jsonData:
    message = item.get("message")
    print message
```

I'm not totally sure what I should be doing here. After doing the HTTP request is it correct that I need to create a JSON and then convert it to a python object? Currently I'm getting the error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `.json()` method on requests object already return a proper dict. No need to parse it. So just do `j = r.json()`.

Use `json.load` to get a dict from [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) and `json.loads` with strings.